# Android client server application with Java + Python with Flask

Tags: python, java, android, flask

How can I rewrite my code so that at startup the client connects to the server and waits for a response from it. Those. connected once, and did not send endless requests. Server, in turn, knew that they were connected to it (saved information about the client) and sent information without request if the client was available.

Client code:

```
package com.example.moex_robot_client;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder().url("http://10.0.2.2:5000/").build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
                runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Network not found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
                TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                assert response.body() != null;
                textView.setText(response.body().string());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

On the server side so far only returns a message on the root. I will also be glad to link to a good example from the Internet.

Comment: `Android client server application` ? Those are big words for one simple http get call. Please rephrase.

Comment: Hmm... It's silly to lay out all the code.